# What's the best strategy to test a new feature set using Mercurial

Tags: mercurial

I have setup a repository in Mercurial that contains all the new development code (and I'm using the stable branch that contains the stable releases).

What's the best strategy to use when I want to test a new feature but keep it isolated from the default branch?

That is something that I want to put in the default branch only when I'm sure that it's working properly. I don't think that creating branches for each new feature would make sense.

I remember reading something about creating a temporary branch and then removing it if everything is working as expected.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I don't think that creating branches for each new feature would make sense.

Re-think about it. "Branch per task" is perfectly correct and valid workflow: you separate your changes from mainline (but can sync /get changes from/ default), finished and tested changes can be integrated to mainline (merge branch) or abandoned (close branch) and you'll return to clean point in history

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So you suggest that you create a new branch when you are working at a big new feature and then you merge that into the main branch? Will then I get a lot of branches with all the tasks done? Right now I have the default and the stable branch (which I like to keep things clean)

Comment: @AndreaNagar - yes, you *may have* a lot of branches, but *why* it must to worry you?

Comment: @AndreaNagar: You should merge the main branch into your feature branch regularly to make sure they don't diverge too far. But don't merge the feature branch into the main branch until it's done and you're pretty sure it's fairly free of bugs.

Comment: If those features are simple enough, then you could use bookmarks instead and avoid too many branches.

Comment: @xr09 - anon branches or bookmarks are not ideal (really - useless Git-style bullshit) from historical POV.For "How this feature was implemented" question and automated answer named branches is best choice

Comment: @xr09 - "lightweight branching", if you are interesting in **only process and result**, and *not in easy discoverable coding-history* later

Answer (score 1):

You (every serious developer) need a systematic branching model, instead of a number of random best strategies or tips. Search for git-flow and hg-flow.